# Property name of VO class has changed when I transferred data between view and controller

Tags: java, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I use AngularJs + Bootstrap + SpringMvc in my project. I create a VO class to transform data between page and controller. There is a boolean property named "isDefined" in VO class, But when view get data , it becomes "defined". I changed the name to other things like "isFired" and the view just get "fired". Why could that happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide code with description. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using primitive `boolean` not wrapper `Boolean` for these properties, so the getter of them will be is{}, if you want to use these names change their type to `Boolean`